# Class size is different across modules (DLLs). How and why?

Tags: c++, memory, shared

I have two Visual Studio 2015 C++ projects, namely `A` and `B`. `A` is compiled as a shared library and `B` uses it. They both utilize a class `Foo` defined in `A`.

The problem occurs at a line in `B` that looks like:

```cpp
auto p = std::make_shared<Foo>(3);
```

raising an `AccessViolationException`.

I realized that `A` and `B` recognize the size of `Foo` differently and that it makes the constructor of `Foo` in `B` go over the boundary of memory allocated by `A`'s `make_shared`. Using the Watch window of Visual studio, I could see `sizeof(Foo)` is 1832 when the code is running in `A` module, while the same watch entry gives a value of 1813 when the code is running in `B` module.

I tried to delete all intermediate and output files of both projects and rebuild the entire solution but never helped.

So, how can a single class can appear in different sizes in different modules? What determines the memory layout of a class? Finally and most importantly, how can I fix the problem?

Comment: Maybe different preprocessor flags leading to different objects/subobject sizes? Hard to crystal ball this without a [mcve]. 1800 bytes is a massive size for a class in any case... I would recommend inspecting subobject `sizeof`s until you find a difference, then repeat that recursively until you can find the root cause.

Comment: I suppose that projects setting are different and for one padding was added and for another wasn't

Comment: This is commonly caused by mixing code compiled in debug and release (they have a different size for common classes such as `std::string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot reason about object sizes (or layout) from a purist stand point unless one of the following is true:

*The type is a [standard layout type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_standard_layout).*

**or**

*Everything about the build is constant - in particular compiler flags, compiler used, compiler version, etc.*

---

> Finally and most importantly, how can I fix the problem ?

Bascily you have 2 options.

Use a standard layout type *or* make sure it's build the same way. For this reason, most publicly available DLL or shared library interfaces doens't use *advanced* types (ie. non standard-layout) in their interfaces and some even stay with [c](/questions/tagged/c) compatible code (sometime to actually be compatible with [c](/questions/tagged/c)).